How does a believer add to his faith?
Concerning 2 Peter 1:5, is the power given as effort is exacted?

For this very reason, make every effort to add to your faith goodness; and to goodness, knowledge; (2 Peter 1:5, NIV)


Since faith is 'the gift of God' and is granted 'without works' it follows that these other virtues will follow in like manner. (Not with human 'effort'.)

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 17,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the Community of users to maintain the integrity of the site.

Please clarify what you mean by "the power given" and "is exacted."

Believers have been gifted saving faith by God, and that miracle of grace opens up a new life to them. Although only one verse in chapter 1 has been asked about here, reading from verse 1 through to verse 12 establishes the context, into which verse 5 sits nicely.
Peter is addressing those who (like him) have the same precious faith through the righteousness of God and their Saviour, Jesus Christ (verse 1.)
Through their knowledge of God and Christ, they have on-going grace and peace (verse 2).
God's power has given them  all things pertaining to life and godliness, which is linked to knowledge of him (verse 3).
They have also been given wonderful promises, by which they may be partakers of the divine nature, having escaped worldly corruption and lust (verse 4).
Therefore, they are to be diligent to add to their faith virtue and knowledge (verse 5).
To that they are also to add self-control, patience, godliness, brotherly kindness, and charity (verses 6 to 7).
Now, the question is, how are all those other things to be added to the believer's faith?  Verse 9 links spiritual blindness and forgetting having been purged from one's old sins as impediments. Not only that, but they will prevent the believer from being fruitful in their knowledge of Jesus Christ. A spiritual barrenness will obtain (verse 8).
The antidote to that is diligence to enter in to the abundance of the everlasting Kingdom (verses 10 to 11). They are to keep remembering what they have been delivered from, to consider the wonder of what they have been ushered into - the kingdom of God, which has been established in truth (verse 12).
This speak against complacency. Tragically, some believers seem to think that they can now relax; it's all been done, and they are on their way to heaven. Other believers begin to forget what they have been saved from, and can drift back into their old, sinful, lazy and worldly ways. Yet others expect that by doing a bit of routine Bible reading themselves and just sitting back to be spoon-fed once or twice a week while listening to whatever they are told from a pulpit, that that will suffice. Peter adds a warning about being deceived by cunningly devised fables (verse 16).
God has given every power needed to grow spiritually strong and mature, to be fruitful in the knowledge of Christ. The Holy Spirit guides and leads into that truth. As believers reflect on the thrilling transformation God has wrought in them, they will rise up in adoration and wonder, to draw ever closer to their loving God. They will soak up all the means God has provided for their growth, applying themselves in obedience and appreciation. That is how their faith is added to.

Edifying and uplifting. High quality literature. Up-voted +1. Greatly appreciated.

What is faith? Faith is the mind+conscience-based assuredness that Christ is Lord in whom there dwells the entire richness of the Father (cf. Colossians 2:9), to the effect that all blessings of the Father are and can be effected only through and in Christ (cf. 2 Cor. 1:20).
Now, since it is so, then it is only natural that through faith we shall get access to those uncreated divine treasures which Father wants to give to us through Christ and Holy Spirit.
Thus, we shall easily find ourselves in a position of standing in front of the perspective and joyful obligation of infinite growth in God, getting more and more saturated with His wonderful and unfathomable features - goodness, beauty, power, mercifulness, longsuffering, forgiveness, wisdom etc. - that make us divine through greater and fuller participation in them.
Yes, surely our initiative and efforts in faith matters, for without our efforts and synergy with Christ’s grace, our faith will remain sterile and even die off, for as James writes, “faith without deeds is dead” (James 2:14).

Your last paragraph, which I don’t know enough church history to confirm or refute, may prove thorny for upvotes for your answer, so if it’s core to your answer then obviously leave it (but I’d expand it greatly with copious explanation with references and quotes so readers like me can assess your assertion), otherwise I’d remove it. I for one would hesitate to upvote in this state b/c I’d be upvoting an assertion (the final paragraph) that I do not know to be correct or false, and also it’s likely to prove controversial (again fine if central, otherwise not ideal).

Also your first paragraph reads as though faith lives only in the intellect, a sterile reasoned thing, but the rest of your answer (I’m excluding the final paragraph in this) very much shows that faith is a matter of the heart—of loving joyful trust in God because of knowledge of him. So you might want to consider rewording your first paragraph. Might be worth directly quoting one or more passages that define faith rather than paraphrasing because I think your paraphrase tripped you up a bit with wording. Otherwise a great answer (again I’m excluding the last paragraph per above).

@bob ok, you are right, it is not essential to bring in additional issue that require further explanations and references. But please do not upvote my answer for this acknowledgment only.

@bob As to “intellect”, I use this word not in the sense of “brains”, but in the sense of νούς, the conscience, which is most precious that humans have and that precedes even faith, for unless faith is based on a pure voice of conscience, such a faith is not worthy of being embraced.

I can’t really argue one way or another there as I’m unfamiliar with that definition, and I think that may be the problem, because I think you’re using non-standard words to describe biblical concepts (based on the rest of your answer). But many unfortunately consider faith to be a purely intellectual thing, something that can be reasoned out based on evidence with no accompanying love or trust or relationship at all with God, and that’s not biblical faith, which involves the heart (see Proverbs 3:5-6). That’s why I think there’s a wording issue. You know what you meant, but others might not.

@bob Faith is connected deeply with feelings, but more primarily to the conscience/mind, because it is written that "faith comes from hearing the word of God" (Romans 10:17), that is to say, if one hears the preaching of Apostles and their interpretation of the Bible and Christ as the fulfilment of the Law, and conscientiously weighs it, then one comes to understanding of truthfulness of the preaching and through this understanding legitimately embraces the faith. Woe to those who embrace faith only out of a feeling, such are many a heretics, such are Mormons, who invented their own Bible.

Faith comes by hearing God's Word (scripture):
Romans 10:14-17
"How then shall they call on him in whom they have not believed? and how shall they believe in him of whom they have not heard? and how shall they hear without a preacher?
15 And how shall they preach, except they be sent? as it is written, How beautiful are the feet of them that preach the gospel of peace, and bring glad tidings of good things!
16 But they have not all obeyed the gospel. For Esaias saith, Lord, who hath believed our report?
17 So then faith cometh by hearing, and hearing by the word of God."
2 Timothy 2:15
"Study to shew thyself approved unto God, a workman that needeth not to be ashamed, rightly dividing the word of truth."

While some may down vote this based on tier particular doctrine, Mark has provided clear evidence from the scripture that faith does come from hearing. It may come in other ways too but Rom 10 is quite clear.

@DanFefferman You will someday know what your words of encouragement mean.  Thank you.

I'd be clearer: faith comes from the word of God and speech is heard.

@civitas Thank you for the suggestion.

In 2 Peter 1:5, the believer is exhorted to "add to your faith virtue, and to virtue knowledge..." and continues with a list of Christian virtues that must be cultivated. The question is whether the power for these virtues is given as a result of effort or through divine grace. This connects with the argument from Galatians 3:5, where Paul asks if the Spirit and the miracles among the Galatians come from the works of the law or from the "hearing of faith."
The Greek terms "ἐπιχορηγῶν" (epichorēgōn, "supplies" or "provides") in Galatians 3:5 and "πίστεως" (pisteōs, "faith") also appear in 2 Peter 1:5. In 2 Peter, the believer is called to "add" to faith, implying active participation, but this act of adding is done by the power provided by God. The same divine power that enables the believer to grow in faith is not a reward for legalistic works but is a result of God's grace in response to faith.
Thus, in both passages, the believer's effort is not the source of power, but faith (in both its hearing and action) activates the divine provision. The effort to "add to faith" in 2 Peter 1:5 is not done to earn the Spirit or power but as a response to the Spirit already at work through faith. In other words, the effort of the believer is exercised through the grace that comes by faith, which is made available not through legal works, but through hearing and responding to the word of God in faith.
This understanding aligns with the broader biblical teaching that faith precedes and activates God's work in the believer's life. The process of adding to faith is a cooperative effort where the believer responds to the divine grace already provided through faith, rather than working to earn it. The power for growth in virtues is given by God, not earned by human effort or legal adherence. Therefore, in both Galatians 3:5 and 2 Peter 1:5, the power is supplied through faith and grace, and the believer's role is one of receiving, responding, and growing.

+1 Without him we can do nothing. Arm of flesh will always fail. We grow with the inward working of God in us. Knowing what God is working in you and actively cooperating with that work is the foundation. Phil.2:13 and Eph 3:20 come to mind. We add to our faith the knowledge of his inward working within us.

2 Peter 1:5-7 (NIV)

5 For this very reason, make every effort to add to your faith goodness; and to goodness, knowledge; 6 and to knowledge, self-control; and to self-control, perseverance; and to perseverance, godliness; 7 and to godliness, mutual affection; and to mutual affection, love.

Jesus summarizes "Love" as the greatest commandment. In Matthew 22:37-40, He says;

37 Jesus replied: “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’ 38 This is the first and greatest commandment. 39 And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ 40 All the Law and the Prophets hang on these two commandments.”

Jesus also emphasizes "Love" among His disciples in John 13:34-35;

34 “A new command I give you: Love one another. As I have loved you, so you must love one another. 35 By this everyone will know that you are my disciples, if you love one another.”

In the Parable of the Mustard Seed (Matthew 13:31-32; Mark 4:30-32 and Luke 13:18-19), the Lord plants a little faith in the human heart, expecting it to grow. Then in Luke 13:6-9, the Parable of the Fruitless Fig Tree, the Lord intends to remove the fruitless fig tree, but the caretaker suggests giving it another chance and commits to nurturing it.
"Faith" does not come all at once, it requires nurturing, much like the growth of a mustard seed. When one has a little faith and is obedient to the Lord, in turn, the Lord provide guidance to nurture them further. This positive cycle ultimately brings their faith to fullness. This is the meaning of the mysterious statement, frequently mentioned in Matthew 13:12; 25:29 and Luke 8:18 and 19:26:

Whoever has will be given more

